# Background check - Aggregating the work for a parent company and its wholly owned subsidiary

Tags: background-check

I am currently going through background checks for a company after receiving a verbal offer letter. In my resume, I had grouped my previous experience for a parent company and its whole owned subsidiary as one under the parent company, as I moved from parent company to the subsidiary when it was created.

Although I have mentioned about the subsidiary in the resume, I didn't make a separate entry for it. In the background verification form, I have made separate entries for the two, even though I mentioned in the form that the subsidiary is owned by parent company. 
I did an internship in the parent company with a month gap between starting the full time and I have put the start date as the start date of internship.

I am anxious now if it can have a negative impact on my background verification. I have all the certificates and relieving letter that confirm my history in case they ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have tried to represent your situation as best as you can, and you have the documentation to back it up if asked.

I think you're probably overthinking it. There's no clear intent to misrepresent and any background checks will align with what is on your resume.

Take a deep breath and wait to see if you get asked anything further. If you do, then just supply the documentation that confirms your statement.

Comment: The other argument for aggregating the experience is not looking like a resume is being needlessly padded. This goes both ways -- I'd view this aggregation as a good thing.